OutOfMemoryError with Apache Calcite and Avatica for Large Result Sets Despite Setting Fetch Size
I'm using Apache Calcite with Avatica to build a custom JDBC driver for querying a PostgreSQL database. The setup works fine for smaller datasets, but when executing SELECT * queries on large tables, I encounter a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. It appears that Calcite attempts to load the entire result set into memory, which overwhelms the heap.
What I've Tried:

Overriding LocalService to Set Fetch Size and Max Rows:
I have overridden the apply method in an extended LocalService class to set fetch size and maximum rows per frame:
@Override
public Service.ExecuteResponse apply(Service.PrepareAndExecuteRequest request) {
    // Set limits to prevent memory issues
    long maxRowsTotal = 1000;
    int frameMaxSize = 100;

    Service.PrepareAndExecuteRequest prepareAndExecuteReq = new Service.PrepareAndExecuteRequest(
            request.connectionId, request.statementId, request.sql, maxRowsTotal, frameMaxSize);

    return super.apply(prepareAndExecuteReq);
}


Setting Fetch Size in the Custom JDBC Driver:
I’ve added the following property to the connection configuration in my custom JDBC driver:
info.setProperty(BuiltInConnectionProperty.FETCH_SIZE.camelName(), "1000");



Issue:
Despite these changes, the fetch size is not being propagated to the underlying PostgreSQL PgStatement. When I inspect the PgStatement, both maxRows and fetchSize are 0, and Calcite still tries to load all rows into memory.
Questions:

How can I ensure Calcite or Avatica respects the fetch size and fetches data in batches?
Is there a better way to handle large result sets with Calcite/Avatica to avoid OutOfMemoryError?
Is there any setting I might be missing in Calcite or Avatica to enable proper batching?

Background:

I'm building a virtual layer on top of a PostgreSQL data warehouse using Calcite.
Each customer queries their own database instance via this virtual layer.
The system needs to handle large datasets efficiently.

Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated!
